# Async драйвер для pysqlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, async-await, асинхронность

Пытаюсь сделать асинхронную сессию для работы с бд, но столкнулся вот с такой ошибкой:

```
"The asyncio extension requires an async driver to be used. "
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: The asyncio extension requires an async driver to be used. The loaded 'pysqlite' is not async.
```

Код:

```
engine = create_async_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=False)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
session_db = session()
```

Погуглив понял, что использую синхронный драйвер pysqlite, но асинхронного найти не могу.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682336/async-sqlite-python

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать aiosqlite: https://github.com/omnilib/aiosqlite
Для создания `AsyncEngine` нужно добавить драйвер к url: `engine = create_async_engine('sqlite+aiosqlite:///test.db', echo=False)`